# jQuery animate callback with promise still fires too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback

I scroll my homepage back up if the logo in my menu is clicked. I also have a listener on `$(window).scroll()` which animates an object out of the screen with a negative margin.

My problem is that this event gets triggered with the animation (animate `scrollTop`).

This shouldn't occur because I have a boolean variable which has to be true to do this, I only set this on true AFTER the scroll animation using a combination of `.promise()` and `.done()`.

This is my JavaScript:

```
var firstscroll=true;

$(function(){


    var captionWidth= $(".caption").children().size() * 35;
    $(".caption").width(captionWidth);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if(firstscroll){
        $(".hidden-menu").removeClass("hidden-menu", {duration:500});
        $('.header').animate({
            marginTop: $('.header').height() * -1
         }, 500);
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
         }, 500);
         firstscroll = false;
      }
    });

    $(".menu-logo, .logo-container").click(function(){
        $('.header').animate({
            marginTop: 0
         }, 500);
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
            }, 500).promise().done(resetFirstScroll());
    });
});

var resetFirstScroll = function() {
  firstscroll=true;
}
```

A solution would be to give the function a `setTimeout` of 50 milliseconds, but I'd rather do it correctly after the animation is completed.

Using the standard callback gives the same output:

```
    $(".menu-logo, .logo-container").click(function(){
        $('.header').animate({
            marginTop: 0
         }, 500);
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
            }, 500, function() {
                resetFirstScroll();
            });
    });
});

var resetFirstScroll = function() {
  firstscroll=true;
}
```

Comment: `.promise().done(resetFirstScroll);`

Answer (score 0):

For those who want the "hacky" solution:

```
var firstscroll=true;

$(function(){


    var captionWidth= $(".caption").children().size() * 35;
    $(".caption").width(captionWidth);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if(firstscroll){
        $(".hidden-menu").removeClass("hidden-menu", {duration:500});
        $('.header').animate({
            marginTop: $('.header').height() * -1
         }, 500);
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
         }, 500);
         firstscroll = false;
      }
    });

    $(".menu-logo, .logo-container").click(function(){
        $('.header').animate({
            marginTop: 0
         }, 500);
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
            }, 500, function() {
            setTimeout( resetFirstScroll, 50 );
            });
    });
});

var resetFirstScroll = function() {
  firstscroll=true;
}
```